# Connect 3 switches without dpdt switch

Tags: switches, relay

Is it even possible to do such a thing?
I am trying to implement home automation at my home, and I have a bunch of [these relays](http://www.banggood.com/20Pcs-SONGLE-Mini-12V-DC-Power-Relay-SRD-12VDC-SL-C-PCB-Type-p-955804.html).
I don't want to need to get dpdt ones, and they are expensive.
P.S. I am trying to create a 4-way switch using 3-way relays.

Comment: You left out necessary information from your question. Mainly, what do you mean by "connect 3 switches"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you aren't able to simply make a remote button that toggles the single relay contained in another switch. That would be the obvious choice. Actually, so obvious that I have to assume you're asking how to create a traditional three-way switch using SPST relays.

The answer then is yes, you can create a three-way switch using SPST relays, but you need to essentially create SPDT switches with two relays and some control logic.

The SPST relay schematic would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTuzpW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that '!A' means NOT A, that is the opposite of A. If A is on then !A is off and if A is off then !A is on. The same applies, of course, for B.

I don't think you'll save much money and you certainly won't save complexity. You should just buy the correct parts.

Comment: It appears from the [honest-to-god data sheet](http://www.songle.com/en/pdf/20084141716341001.pdf) that the relays **ARE** SPDT (form "C")

Answer (score 0):

With some logic I found the answer!

You can create a 4-way relay from 2 3-way relays(Rel1,Rel2). It will be used along with 2 3-way switches for a hallway.

You connect the NC of Rel1 to NO of Rel2, and NC of Rel2 to NO of Rel1.

Then you use NC of Rel1 and NC of Rel2 as the connect points for the first 3-way switch. 
And then you use the relay inputs of Rel1 and Rel2 as the connect points for the second 3-way switch.